# Issues running grails on a remote environment

Tags: java, exception, grails, localhost

I have a server that is "named" and it seems to cause Grails to be unable to find localhost.

```
Running Grails application..
2011-01-12 20:45:14,046 [main] ERROR ehcache.Cache  - Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: zaftra: zaftra
java.net.UnknownHostException: zaftra: zaftra
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1426)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:143)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:463)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:369)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:445)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:302)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:260)
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider.start(EhCacheProvider.java:128)
```

Contents of `/etc/hosts` (as shown):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain zaftra
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain zaftra
```

Comment: Can you provide your system architecture and the contents (or a brief snippet) of your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: @Rob: Done. System architecture is a cloud server running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're on some flavor of linux. If that's the case, you might have a look at your `/etc/hosts` file - is there an entry for `localhost`? I'd expect to see something like:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost zaftra
::1           localhost
```

I did some Googling - there's a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/109148/problem-with-tomcat-and-getlocalhost-exception) over on SuperUser - the suggestion there was to add the following to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
search (domainname) // in your case, search (zaftra)
```

You might also try:

```
search zaftra
// or
search zaftra.example.com // if there's a more fully-qualified domain name you can use
```

(That's based off of an entry I've got in `resolv.conf` on one of my Ubuntu machines).

Comment: This was left off when creating the server. Completely forgot to check.

Comment: I'm going to tick this as accepted, because it's very likely that these two changes will resolve other problems. I'm still getting it though. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AWS(running amazon linux) and ran into the exact same issue, my fix was to add this to /etc/hosts:

```
102.130.27.257     LAMP-LIVE01-N123     www.mydomain.com
```

where those values came from:

```
{internal IP}     {instance name}     {domain for grails app}
```

and then I restarted httpd and my grails app server(tomcat)